# Comparing two columns in one core data table

Tags: core-data, compare, tableview

I have 1 table with in which i need to compare the values. If they dont match highlight those table view cell.

### Table has column

### XXX            YYYY

MH_01          MH_02

MH_02          MH_03

MH_04          Mh_05

What it need to check is that row[1]YYYY=row[2] XXX if not then it should highlight that cell in a row. like in this example it will highlight(YYYY-(MH_03) and xxxx(MH_04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement transient properties on your model object for the next and previous entry. Then create two more transient properties on your model object to return a NSColor or whatever you need to display the highlighting of the cell.

You can then either populate the next and prev properties in your table's datasource. If you are using NSArrayController as a datasource, you can easily subclass NSArrayController to populate next and previous for you.

```
-(NSArray *)arrangeObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    NSArray * arrangedObjects = [super arrangeObjects:objects];

    NSManagedObject * previousEntry;
    for (NSManagedObject * entry in arrangedObjects)
    {
        [previousEntry setValue:entry forKey:@"nextEntry"];
        [entry setValue:previousEntry forKey:@"prevEntry"];
        previousEntry = entry;
    }

    return arrangedObjects;
}
```